# How do I make an executable that readelf would say is UNIX - System V?

Tags: unix, architecture, gnu, target-platform

I have been making programs for ages that are under 800K on Linux Fedora 19 using GCC 4.8.1.  The readelf utility has reported them as OS/ABI = "UNIX - System V" (byte 8 is zero).

Now suddenly the binaries are turning out over 1MB and readelf is saying they are "UNIX - GNU" (byte 8 is 3).  Not my doing!  Something is having an influence and I'm not sure what.

For instance, now, using nm, I find that the functions __nss_hosts_lookup2 and openat are being linked in, which weren't there before.

How do I make an executable again that readelf would say is UNIX - System V ?

Comment: What is the real problem, the size or the output of readelf?

Comment: The size of the executable, containing lots of unnecessary functions.  The readelf utility is just reporting correctly what it's supposed to.

Comment: But also the real problem that I find worrying is that this has suddenly started happening without me asking it to, and without me making any change to the source or the makefile.

Answer (score 2):

I found it!  All on my own.  The linker was picking up the October 2007 versions of libc.a libm.a and libstdc++.a in the library directory I supplied (providing 780K executables).  After deleting those files it started picking up the March 2013 versions and so bloated the executable (1.1M).  I'll have to leave it bloated unfortunately because I don't want to have to find all the necessary header files (as of course the header files should match the libraries).  I don't blame the software writers for not putting one function per source/object file.  I blame the linker for still not dragging in function by function granularity and doing cyclic library search as standard.